# How do I make HTML or CSS tables work inside my paragraph tags?

Tags: html, css

I am making a simple table on my website that needs to be within `<p>` tags.  The table can be CSS or HTML, but the problem is that it always breaks my paragraph and ends the style.  using `display:block;` and `display:inline;` did not do anything.

Why won't this work?
And if it can't, what should I do instead?

Comment: Need to see code. No idea what you mean by charts.

Comment: keep the chart out of the <p> and apply some float:left on your chart. That should wrap the text around.

Comment: Sadly, that wont work.  My styling includes a box around the paragraph and a font color.  It all breaks when I add the chart.

Comment: Can you explain what that is?

Comment: @Bit Fracture If you post some of your code on http://jsfiddle.net/ we can get a better idea of what you're trying to do.

Comment: http://bitfracture.com/?page=computers  
Here is my test chart that needs to be inside the paragraph.  It is all too much code to post.

Comment: tables shouldn't be inside paragraphs

Comment: instead of enclosing your table in a paragraph, could you enclose it in a div?

Comment: I understand that they shouldn't be in paragraphs.  But clearly someone has done it.  Not everyone has a screwy chart.  Also, the chart is now in a div, with the CSS one.  And still no go.

Comment: Still not specified what a “chart” is here. Still no reason why it should be in a paragraph. A `p` element *cannot* contain a table, by HTML syntax and by browser parsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three types of CSS declaration :

1. Internal CSS - Defined under HEAD section of current webpage .
2. Inline CSS - Defined under given within particular element.
3. External CSS - Defined in external style sheet and is linked to the web page.

Avoid using Inline CSS, as it will be specific to given element and you will not be able to continue with other elements.

It is best to have External CSS where once properties for given tag is defined, it will automatically get implemented in every corresponding tags.

Internal CSS will also work but it will just increase the downloadable size of html.